# jQuery background-position animation to run more smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a pattern background animation in jQuery made like this.

```
        banner.css('backgroundPosition', x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px');

        window.setInterval(function() {
            banner.css("backgroundPosition", x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px');
            y--;
        }, 150);
```

Live example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emMxXa

But it is rather 'jittery'.
How can I make something like this to run more smoothly and slowly.

Comment: Reduce the interval delay so you get more frames per second: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByrbWO

Comment: I suggest the value of 50, moves quicker though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use and look into *CSS transitions* and *CSS animations* for real smoothyness.

```
-webkit-animation: move 30s linear 0s infinite alternate;
-moz-animation: move 30s linear 0s infinite alternate;

@-webkit-keyframes move { 
  from { background-position: 0px 0px } to { background-position: 0px 400px }  
}

@-moz-keyframes move { 
  from { background-position: 0px 0px } to { background-position: 0px 400px }  
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaEMvy

Comment: Thanks. I've also found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087518/animate-css-background-position-with-smooth-results-sub-pixel-animation

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85eabcr9/).

You will see that by reducing the interval value from 150 to 30 it will be a lot smoother:

```
             window.setInterval(function() {
                banner.css("backgroundPosition", x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px');
                y--;
                //x--;

                //if you need to scroll image horizontally -
                // uncomment x and comment y

            }, 30);
```

You can lower it even more but the more you lower it, the faster it gets also.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame

```
(function($) {

        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        //cache a reference to the banner
        var banner = $("#banner");

        // set initial banner background position
        banner.css('backgroundPosition', x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px');

        // scroll up background position every 90 milliseconds
        function step() {
            banner.css("backgroundPosition", x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px');
            y--;
            //x--;

            //if you need to scroll image horizontally -
            // uncomment x and comment y
                    window.requestAnimationFrame(step)
        }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);

})(jQuery);
```